# Why is my question not being answered?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I asked [Data feed from Google Docs API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366337/data-feed-from-google-docs-api) and it got 9 views, but no responses. Why is this? I have tagged it with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [php](/questions/tagged/php), [xml](/questions/tagged/xml), [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) and [google-docs-api](/questions/tagged/google-docs-api). There should be a lot of people who can answer questions on this subject. It is a clearly written question, explaining what I have already tried and examples of the code.

I just don't understand why there are not more views, and why there are no answers or even comments.

How do questions just drop off the radar on Stack Overflow, where other questions provoke a huge response?

Comment: Radical thought, but perhaps no one knows the answer.

Comment: There isn't a timeframe set to get answers. If the question is clear, somebody will reply; if the problem you are describing is too specific, then it is probable you would get few answers, and not immediately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like your question got answered now.

Why not earlier? Some ideas:

- Your question has the title **Data feed from google docs API**, which does not really indicate what your problem might be. This way less people are looking at it (which coincides with your *9 views*).
- You asked at Friday afternoon/evening (depending on time zone), when less people are there.
- The answer is really specific for neither [php](/questions/tagged/php), [xml](/questions/tagged/xml), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) nor [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), so if specialists of either of these fields looked at it, and didn't know anything about the Google docs API (and didn't care enough to try it themselves), they couldn't really help you.
- You actually said in your question that you can access the URL from the browser even if not logged in, which seems to be not quite true (if reading the accepted answer). This might have deterred someone from posting this idea as an answer.